# Orientation binary image seems shifted when extracting coordinates of nonzero pixels

Tags: python, binary, coordinates, scatter, imshow

I have a pretty large binary jpg file. The idea is to extract a small part and find shapes. Later on I want to make a shape file of the shapes. The steps I take:
1. Load image and crop it
2. Blur image 
3. Skeletonize image
4. Extract coordinates nonzero values of skeletonized image 
5. Do some interpolation (not shown in code)
6. Convert coordinates (I just added the difference) such that it will have the same coordinates it originally had inside the large image (before cropping) 
7. Extract geo reference data from tiff file of same size original jpg. Bind these to our shapes and create shape file. 
My final shape file product appeared to be flipped. So I checked throughout my coding process and the orientation of the image appears to change after I extracted the coordinates. When I used imshow to show the matrices, the orientation was all fine. When I used scatter to show the coordinates of the points, the orientation was off.

```
ds = gdal.Open(‘path_to/binary.jpg')
image = ds.ReadAsArray()
image_crop = image[28500:30000,25500:28000]

def blur(image,resblur):
    blur = cv2.blur(image,(resblur,resblur))
    blur = (blur-np.min(blur))/(np.max(blur)-np.min(blur))
    blur[blur<=np.mean(blur)] = 0
    blur[blur!=0]=1
    return blur

blur = blur(image_crop,50)
plt.imshow(blur)

def skel_coordinates(blur):
    skel = skeletonize(blur)
    skel = np.uint8(skel)

    y,x = np.nonzero(skel)
    coords = np.transpose(np.vstack([x, y]))
    return skel, coords

skel,coords = skel_coordinates(blur)
plt.imshow(skel)
plt.imshow(coord[:,0],coord[:,1])

x = x + 25500
y = y + 28500
```

Comment: Is there a reason you transposed the coordinates before returning them? What do you mean by the shapes being "flipped", i.e. in what direction? Mirrored / turned?

Comment: I transposed it because I needed a shape of (..,2) instead of (2,..) for a later step: 
tree = KDTree(coords)
nearest_dist, nearest_ind = tree.query(coords,k=8))

The scatter plot is mirrored on the x-axis, while the end result (shapefile) is mirrored on the y-axis.

Comment: Where is the `skeletonize` function defined? Could it be that the `x,y` coordinates got switched at some point?

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot to state that. I am using skeletonize from skimage.morphology. As input it only requires the image.

Comment: Alright, skeletonize doesn't seem to reverse coordinate order, so how come you return it to `y,x` and not `x,y`? Just trying to figure out the steps here to see where it could go wrong.

Comment: I don't know actually. I checked everything and the shapefile output seems to be correct if I change 'y,x = np.nonzero(skel)
    coords = np.transpose(np.vstack([x, y])) ' to  ' x,y = np.nonzero(skel)
    coords = np.transpose(np.vstack([y,x]))'. I don't know why I will need np.vstack([y,x]) instead of [x,y]. I am thinking that maybe the mirrored image of the scatter plot in comparison with the imshow image has to do with that imshow starts the y-axis from 0 at the top, while scatter has 0 at the bottom.